# Sympy integrate does not give the right answer

Tags: python, sympy

The [standard logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) is coded as `sigma` in the following code:

```
from sympy import *
x, sigma = symbols("x sigma")
sigma = 1/(1 + exp(-x))
plot(sigma);
```

[image: logistic function]

When you try calculate the area below the curve for negative `x`:

```
integrate(sigma,(x, -oo, 0))  # This gives NaN
```

If you need the right answer you need to calculate the following limit, that gives `log(2)` as it must be.

```
t = symbols("t")
limit(integrate(sigma, (x, -t, 0)), t, oo) # log(2)
```

Why `SymPy`is not integrating sigma properly?

Comment: What version of sympy are you using?  Using 0.7.4.1 I get `log(2)` using both snippets.

Comment: Version: 0.7.6.1 , and I'm working with Jupyter

Comment: It appears the version of sympy at [live.sympy.org](http://live.sympy.org) suffers from the same problem.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me introduced somewhere since January 2014... you may want to make a post on their [issue tracker](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues) and reference this post.

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/10665

Comment: >>> (x + log(1 + exp(-x))).subs(x, -oo)
===> nan

. Integration works well, substitution is the problem.

Comment: By the way, it's solved in the development branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug which has been fixed in the SymPy development branch (and will be fixed in SymPy 1.0, to be released soon).

```
In [31]: sigma = 1/(1 + exp(-x))

In [32]: integrate(sigma,(x, -oo, 0))
Out[32]: log(2)
```